# Ошибка скрипта с функцией Вверх

Tags: javascript

В консоле браузера заметил ошибку:

```html
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> ((index):1063)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-1.7.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.i (jquery-1.7.min.js:3)
```

У меня там стоит простой скрипт:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        var elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
        var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
        if ($.browser.safari) {
            $('body').animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 1100); //1100 - скорость
        } else {
            $('html').animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 1100);
        }
        return false; 
    });
});
</script>
```

- Собственно все работает и раньше не наблюдал ошибки, но хотелось бы понять на будущее, что с ним не так? Файл "jquery-1.7.min.js" довольно старый, но рабочий.

Comment: `console.log(elementClick);` - ?

Comment: `console.log($(elementClick).length);` - ?

Comment: Посмотрите что вы присваиваете в elementClick. Конечно там не будет никакого офсета

Comment: Спасибо. Но, может я намудрил, пожалуйста посмотрите вот на этот вариант: var destination = $console.log($(elementClick).length).offset().top;